# combine date and time column problem

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server 2005

```
Date Time

20060701 090000
20060702 020000
20060703 180000
...
```

Date and Time datatype is varchar

Tried Query

```
select Convert(datetime, Convert(char(10), date, 103) + ' ' + Convert(char(8), time, 108), 103) from table
SELECT
CAST(
        DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, date)) + ' ' +
        DATEADD(Day, -DATEDIFF(Day, 0, time), time)                   
as datetime) from table
```

It showing error as out of range value.

How to solve this issue.

Need Sql Query Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, why are you storing a DATETIME in a VARCHAR?

This should be able to help

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        Val VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO @Table (Val) SELECT '20060701 090102'
INSERT INTO @Table (Val) SELECT '20060702 020000'
INSERT INTO @Table (Val) SELECT '20060703 180000'

SELECT  *,
        CAST(SUBSTRING(Val,1,8) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(Val,10,2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(Val,12,2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(Val,14,2) AS DATETIME)

FROM    @Table
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across a similar issue a few years ago, when importing HL7 messages. Here is a copy of the function I used. It creates a DateTime string with the time component correctly separated into hh:mm:ss, which is needed for the cast to DateTime.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_StringDateTietoDateTime
(
    @Date varchar(15)
)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result DATETIME

    SET @Result = NULL

    If len(@Date) > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @Result = CAST(SUBSTRING(@hl7date, 1, 8) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(@hl7date, 10, 2) + ':' +
            SUBSTRING(@date, 12, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(@date,14, 2) AS DATETIME)
    END

    RETURN @RESULT
END
```